# Directly addressing controls in a UserControl after adding TableLayoutPanel

Tags: winforms, user-controls, tablelayoutpanel

I recently refactored the code of a user control in my WinForms project, and changed it from a user control with text boxes, combo and buttons that were just placed all over it, to a user control that now contains a TableLayoutPanel, which holds all the controls in a better order.

My problem is that in many places the code address the controls nested in the user control directly via the Controls dictionary - for example: `MyUserControl.Controls["NameOfTextBox"].Visible = false;`

Now, after I nested the text boxes and buttons in a TableLayoutPanel, I can't do such addressing anymore, and now I should write `MyUserControl.Controls[0].Controls["NameOfTextBox"].Visible = false;`, because otherwise I get an exception.

My question is whether I should change all my code in every place that addresses the contents of the user control, or can you offer me some workaround to implement on the user control itself, so when I'll try address the controls directly, it will forward it to the contents of the TableLayoutPanel.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

> My problem is that in many places the code address the controls nested in the user control directly...

That's probably the core issue.  Try creating properties for you UserControl instead:

```
public bool NameBoxVisible {
  get { return NameOfTextBox.Visible; }
  set { NameOfTextBox.Visible = value; }
}
```

Then you can reference the controls directly in your UserControl but provide a separation of concern to the consumers of your control.

Comment: For me it looks very redundent to write a getter for every property in every control nested in the user control... Even if i do it only for properties that are  already used from an outside code, it  will force me to edit the code of the user control every time I want to change a property that haven't been used before. Do someone have another idea?